# ng-include with ng-src not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to compile a template which has `data-ng-include` and `data-ng-src` defined. I'm trying to set the src by calling `getPartial()`, which returns the path of the template. But the `getPartial()` is not getting called.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="displayElements();">Display Elements</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.displayElements = function() {
   var template = '<div data-ng-include data-ng-src="getPartial()"></div>';
   var linkFn = $compile(template)($scope);
   //console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById("container")));
   angular.element(document.getElementById("container")).append(linkFn);
}

$scope.getPartial = function() {
   console.log("from partial");
   return 'hello.html';
}
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/ig9TAXVpK4k1bQwi9PQo?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'<div data-ng-include data-ng-src="getPartial()"></div>';
```

replace your code with this

```
'<div data-ng-include data-ng-init="getPartial()" src="htmlToLoad"></div>';



var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

  $scope.displayElements = function() {
   var template = '<div data-ng-include data-ng-init="getPartial()" src="htmlToLoad"></div>';
   var linkFn = $compile(template)($scope);
   //console.log(angular.element(document.getElementById("container")));
   angular.element(document.getElementById("container")).append(linkFn);
}

$scope.getPartial = function() {
    alert("sdfsdfsdf");
   console.log("from partial");
   return 'hello.html';
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`ng-include` uses either its own value or value of `src` attribute to get the path ([see documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)). You're trying to use `ng-src`, which is a [directive in its own right](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc). So you need to do either this:

```
<div data-ng-include="getPartial()"></div>
```

or this:

```
<div data-ng-include data-src="getPartial()"></div>
```

---

On a sidenote, watching a function call result hurts performance. You'd be better served by putting the resolved source path into a scope variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:-

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

  $scope.displayElements = function() {
  var template = '<div data-ng-include data-ng-init="getPartial()" src="htmlToLoad"></div>';
  var linkFn = $compile(template)($scope);

 angular.element(document.getElementById("container")).append(linkFn);
};

$scope.getPartial = function() {
  alert("from partial");
   $scope.htmlToLoad = 'hello.html';
};
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/y3PgeBMVHytftI7NDSq4?p=preview